# Facebook Account Kit and token for business

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

We have 3 apps using the very same user base. Users are able to use these apps with one account. Hence, we are using token_for_business id of facebook users in graph api to be able to recognise them in all 3 apps. However, we cannot find anything about token_for_business like approach in account kit documentations. Hence, we cannot recognise a user in an app, who registered in another app.

Is there anything like token_for_business in Account Kit, or should I request a feature from Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no such feature for AccountKit. Though one way that you can implement this yourself is by storing the phone number (or email, if you use that flow) for each app login and cross reference them in your own data.

Comment: Yeah, we did the exact same thing. Thanks.